# UPDATE a field with sum of other fields with conditions MYSQL

Tags: mysql

My Table structure is as follows

```
counter1|counter1_status|counter2|counter2_status|counter3|counter3_status|valid_counter
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 5                 0             6            1               3               1                XXXX
```

I want a single update query to update valid_counter as  6 + 3 = 9
As counter1_status = 0, counter1 should not be added

Tried following query, but it gives error.

```
UPDATE counter_table 
SET valid_contact = 
SUM((CASE WHEN counter1_status=1 THEN counter1 ELSE 0 END) 
+ (CASE WHEN counter2_status=1 THEN counter2 ELSE 0 END) 
+ (CASE WHEN counter3_status=1 THEN counter3 ELSE 0 END))
```

I can get the sum by using SELECT query without any error, but Update query failed.

Comment: What error does it give you?

Comment: #1111 - Invalid use of group function

Comment: See normalisation. Any answer that does not advise normalisation is simply wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to conditionally store sum of (counter1,counter2,counter3) in the valid_contace field, you may use:

```
UPDATE counter_table 
SET valid_contact = 
(CASE WHEN counter1_status=1 THEN counter1 ELSE 0 END) 
+ (CASE WHEN counter2_status=1 THEN counter2 ELSE 0 END) 
+ (CASE WHEN counter3_status=1 THEN counter3 ELSE 0 END)
where id=5
```

Comment: already tried it. It also gives error -  #1093 - You can't specify target table 'counter_table' for update in FROM clause

Comment: I can't tell whether OP wants all the records to have the same aggregate value or not.

Comment: No, i need a single record update, I will use where condition at the end

Comment: @PramodSahoo Please post your `where clause`

Comment: @PramodSahoo Please note that the `sum` is an aggregate function and operates on all records, not a single record. To get the proper answer, you better clarify your question,

Comment: where id=5, id is primary key in the above table, I didn't show it, I dont think it will affect the query.

Comment: @PramodSahoo Do you want save sum of all records `conters` to the record with `id=5` or you just want to save `counter1+counter2+counter3` in the `valid_contacts` (for recored with `id=5`)?

Comment: I want to save counter1+counter2+counter3 in the valid_contacts (for recored with id=5)

Comment: @PramodSahoo OK, I removed extra codes in my post. now, it gives you the desired action

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE counter_table AS c1 JOIN 
(SELECT id, SUM((CASE WHEN counter1_status=1   THEN counter1 ELSE 0 END) 
    + (CASE WHEN counter2_status=1 THEN counter2 ELSE 0 END) 
    + (CASE WHEN counter3_status=1 THEN counter3 ELSE 0 END)) AS m 
FROM counter_table) AS c2
    USING (id)
    SET c1.`valid_counter` = c2.m;
```

**[Sample fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e128b/2)**

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the solution for error :

SUM should be removed from the query.

It should be SUM(a,b,c)

or a+b+c.

UPDATE counter_table 
SET valid_contact = 
((CASE WHEN counter1_status=1 THEN counter1 ELSE 0 END) 
+ (CASE WHEN counter2_status=1 THEN counter2 ELSE 0 END) 
+ (CASE WHEN counter3_status=1 THEN counter3 ELSE 0 END))